# MySQL querying from multiple tables against a value

Tags: mysql, multiple-tables, join

I'm trying to select data from 3 tables that all share the same column name, I'm not sure how to join the tables together in a query.

Here's my statement so far:

```
SELECT
    *
    FROM
    recipe, recipeingredients, recipesteps
    WHERE
    recipe.recipe_id AND recipeingredients.recipe_id AND recipesteps.recipe_id = :recipe
```

This just seems to return all results from a database rather than only those that match the recipe ID for each. I'm not sure how to perform a table join.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Smells like cartesian product and invalid `WHERE` clause

Comment: Missing conditions in your join...  try this WHERE clause : `code`recipe.recipe_id = :recipe and ecipeingredients.recipe_id =recipe.recipe_id AND recipesteps.recipe_id = recipe.recipe_id`code`

Comment: @Notulysses Yeah it does.

Comment: Can you show us the table definitions for these?

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly provide the JOIN conditions, like this:

```
SELECT recipe.*, recipeingredients.*, recipesteps.*
FROM recipe
JOIN recipeingredients
USING (recipe_id)
JOIN recipesteps
USING (recipe_id)
WHERE recipesteps.recipe_id = :recipe
```

What is does is to first join `recipe` table with `recipeingredients` where rows have same `recipe_id` is both the tables. Same process is then repeated with the `recipesteps` table.

Answer (score 0):

assuming recipie_ID is the unique key combining the tables...

```
SELECT *
FROM recipe r
INNER JOIN recipeingredients ri
 on r.Recipie_ID = RI.Recipie_ID
INNER JOIN recipesteps rs
 on ri.Recipie_ID = Rs.Recipie_ID
WHERE 
R.Recipie_ID = :recipie
```

or using your approach:

```
SELECT *
FROM recipe, recipeingredients, recipesteps
WHERE recipe.recipe_id = recipeingredients.recipe_id
  AND recipeingredients.recipe_id = recipesteps.recipe_id 
  AND recipie.recipie_id = :recipe
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
recipe, recipeingredients, recipesteps
WHERE
recipe.recipe_id = :recipe AND recipeingredients.recipe_id = :recipe AND recipesteps.recipe_id = :recipe
```